# Flutter | switch multilanguage

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make an application that can change many languages, from many tutorials using localization, if using localization we have to write all the text in the application one by one in each json file to the language we want?

can't it automatically translate without having to write it one by one?

Answer (score 1):

> can't it automatically translate without having to write it one by one

No. Automatic translations are really bad without context and apps are very often about single words that are clear in the graphical context of the app, but ambigous or meaningless without.

Example? Lets say you have a dialog asking whether you want to delete an appointment. And you can decide not to. The problem? Both deleting an appointment *and* leaving the dialog in English would be called "Cancel".

Translation is also a business model people don't want you to have for free. Otherwise, what would keep you from writing a translator app?

Translation is available on demand online, but that would mean your app is not available offline, in a tunnel or elevator. Even if available, it would consume lots of traffic. Not ideal.

What you can do is take your file of translations and use an automatic translator to translate that. Then you can use a free translator without any dependencies or traffic bandwidth usage in your app.

I would advise you to have a native speaker proofread this. Contextless translations are *bad*. Really bad. Language at it's core depends on context. At least your primary language and English should be checked by a human.

Comment: If that's bad, do all apps made using Flutter that have a language change feature use the localization method that requires translating each word one by one?

Comment: Yes they do. Believe me, if you had seen an auto-translated one, you would know. If you know more than one language, just try it yourself and auto-translate your localization file. I bet it wil be hilarious for at least 5-10% of your app. Professional app developers hire translators. Hobby projects find volunteers. Real people that can look at the app and translate with context.